# Flex actual CreationComplete event

Tags: events, apache-flex

Which event should I use if I want to make sure
all the nested components inside a component
have been created?

Creationcomplete doesn't seem to work this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the [`creationPolicy`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/layoutperformance_05.html) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090731121621/http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_05.html)) being used. Please go through the link provided to understand why it doesn't work the way you expect it to be.